# Looping and appending to data frame based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have a data frame with a `customer_id` field for customers offered appointments. Each customer gets offered three dates to choose from in another column, and there is another column telling which dates the customer `confirmed`/`rejected`. How do I compare the dates for each unique `customer_id` to find whether the customer chose the `early date offered`, `mid-date offered`, or `latest date offered`?

[image]

Comment: Please, avoid [posting images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). It is a better practice to transcribe them instead.

Comment: What did you try? Please, spend some time reading ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You will get better results by following the tips in those articles.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code works for this special case. It doesn't group the customer, it just compares the col with confirmed and maps the value according to the value in `dates offered`. The downside here is that it only works for this 3 specific dates.
I guess there is a more elegant and especially more generic way to solve this with `groupby` and I hope someone will show it here but for now you could use this:

```
df['new_col'] = df.apply(lambda x: x[1] if x[2] == 'confirmed' else '', axis=1).map({'12/01/2022' : 'earliest date chosen', '13/01/2022' : 'mid date chosen', '14/01/2022' : 'latest date chosen' }).fillna('')
```